# bash-completion for scp on a different port

Tags: bash, scp, bash-completion

I've installed `bash-completion-20060301-1` which gives auto completion of remove directories when using scp.
The problem is that we have many servers that use ssh via port 26.
How can I modify the completion in order for it to note if a -P26 was specified in the scp command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you add such servers to your `ssh_config`, i.e. usually `~/.ssh/config`.

```
Host weirdbox
    User maxim
    Hostname 10.9.8.7
    Port 26
```

Tab completing `scp weirdbox:` will Just Work then.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like to avoid setting up all the hosts in the ssh_config. There's just too many to count...

Comment: I encourage you to make a point of maintaining the `ssh_config` through some kind of script in that case (and likely distribute it through your network). It can potentially help you implement other helpful things for your day-to-day `ssh` use.

Comment: I'll consider that, but I'd still like to know how to do my original question.